# Can VSCode share a project to GitHub like in WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

I want to share a new project to my **GitHub**. Can I do this similar to WebStorm where just click some buttons?

P.S. I could not find nowhere I can log in to GitHub in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code does not provide UI for this. I recommend learning to use the command line for this instead: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

A VS Code extension could also provide UI for this experience however I am not aware of any that do currently.